# How to handle [*] command in TCL

Tags: tcl

Tcl parser is giving error , `invalid command name *` .
I want to handle `*` in TCL.

[a*] is fine as it return (a*)

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

(This is a comment, but I want the formatting of an answer)

You just haven't defined a proc named `*`:

```
$ tclsh
% * foo bar baz
invalid command name "*"
% proc * {args} {puts [lreverse $args]}
% * foo bar baz
baz bar foo
```